# Determining whether or not an expression is an integer

Tags: function-construction, syntax

I'd like to define a function that controls if a certain number is an integer, rational, algebraic and so far. First, I tried generating a list of those numbers:

```
ZL = {1, 3, Pi, E, Sqrt[2], Zeta[3]}
```

I then created my functions like so:

```
TestI[x_] := If[x ∈ Integers, x "is Integer", x "is no Integer"]
```

It works so far.

I now tried to define a For-function like this:

```
For[i = 1, i <= Length[ZL], i++, Print[TestZ[Part[ZL, i]]]]
```

However, when I evaluate the above expression, the output is like

```
is integer
3 is integer
...
is no integer E
```

How can I achieve an output that says:

```
1 is Integer
3 is Integer
...
\e is no Integer
```

and so on?

Comment: `TestI[x_] := 
 If[x \[Element] Integers, ToString[x] <> " is Integer", 
  ToString[x] <> " is no Integer"]` Also, BAD idea to use uppercase for your symbol initials - might clash with built-in symbols.

Comment: `zl = {1, 3, Pi, E, Sqrt[2], Zeta[3]};
testi[x_] := If[IntegerQ[x], x "is Integer", x "is not Integer"];
For[i = 1, i <= Length[zl], i++, Print[testi[Part[zl, i]]]]`

Comment: or `If[Element[x , Integers]`

Comment: @martin Your hint wont work. I get the same results.

Comment: @K.L. If you copy & paste entire first comment what do you get?

Comment: Note that `π` should be entered `Pi`, or "esc `p` esc", not `\pi`. Same with `e`, etc.

Comment: Try `Clear[ZL,zl]` or ClearAll["Global`*"] first

Answer (score 5):

You could achieve without `If`, e.g.:

```
f[x_Integer] := StringForm["`` is an integer", x];
f[x_] := StringForm["`` is not an integer", x];
```

Test:

```
test = {1, 3, Pi, E, Sqrt[2], Zeta[3], Zeta[-2]}
```

Mapping:

```
Column[f /@ test]
```

yields:

[image]

Please note `IntegerQ[3]` is `True`, however `IntegerQ[3.]` is `False`

Comment: Please consider `Listable` too :)